# image loading information with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have a page which has a img holder with the html: -

```
<img src="someimage.jpeg" alt="image" class="show_image"/>
```

Now i m updating the image with jquery using the code...

```
$('.show_image').attr('src', 'anotherimage.jpeg');
```

Now its working fine but i want to show the users the image is being loaded and may wait

as the image size may be huge...

Is there any method in jquery to get the information of percent loaded(bytes read/remaining)

or if the image load is complete...

Also how can i place a div over the image placeholder  such that the

div can fade the image(opacity:0.8) and add some text over the div as loading or something

thanks

Comment: Just curious if using a lightbox would work for you?  Most lightbox plugins will let you use a loading image and will do the fading, caption, and quite a bit more.  http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/ is one of the better ones around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
// change image
$('.show_image').attr('src', 'anotherimage.jpeg');
// image is loading
$('#divID').html('Image is being loaded....');

// image loaded
$('.show_image').load(function(){
  // hide/remove the message
  $('#divID').html('');
});
```

You assign `load` event to the image which fires when image has finished loading. Before that, you can show your message/progress/loader.

Comment: the load function is being called multiple times if i repeatedly chnage the image...example at pradyut.dyndns.org/original_image.jsp#imgid=202 see the console logs...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this kind of info should be provided by the browser and now you can just get notified when the loading is finished by means of **OnLoad** attribute of **img** tag. But you can not get the precise amount of downloaded data, I think.

I suggest you to change your code like this:

```
<img src="someimage.jpeg" alt="image" class="show_image"/>

$('.show_image').attr('src', 'tiny.gif'); // a very small gif animation as loading indicator

$('.show_image').attr('src', 'anotherimage.jpeg');
```

Another solution is to preload the big image like this:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
   var image = new Image();
   image.src = "anotherimage.jpeg";
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <img src="someimage.jpeg" alt="image" class="show_image"/>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
   $('.show_image').src = image.src; // no delay for loading happens
 </script>     
</html>
</body>
```

Comment: great thanks... anything by which i can fadeIn or animate (.showimage)..thanks btw...

Comment: For those kind of animation effects there are lots of libraries, I use Scriptaculous (based on prototype), just search it on Google.